# Link static libraries with functions having the same prototype, but serving different purposes

Tags: c

I am in a weird situation where I need two functions, with the same prototypes, serving different purposes in my program.

My program references to functions in GNU's binary file descriptor package `libbfd.a`, which is generated from `binutils`. I need two `libbfd.a`'s for two targets (e.g. ARM and RISC-V). Apparently, in these two copies of `libbfd.a`'s, there will be a lot of functions having the same prototype (because they are generated from the same `binutils`), but serving different purposes (because their targets are different).

I cannot simply link my program with these two `libbfd.a`'s. Only one copy of the functions gets included in my final program because ...

> The main feature of static libraries is that the symbol index allows you to link in only those `libbfd.a` members that provide missing symbols.

I cannot break the static libraries into object files. There will be `multiple definitions of ...` error while linking.

Either way, the two copies of functions just can't exist in my program simultaneously.

Ultimately, is there an elegant and simple solution to this scenario?

Comment: Apart from the linking, how does your code call these functions? I mean, you'd have to know which one to call, right?

Comment: Create two separate binaries each linked with it's respective target.

Comment: No in C you can't have two functions having the same name and having external linkage. If one of the functions is used only in one compilation unit you may make it **`static`**

Comment: You should do that with dynamic libraries instead. Why can't you use `dlopen` with the `dl` library at runtime ?

Comment: @L.Z. What research did you do? What have you tried?

Comment: @KamilCuk binutils supports multiple targets. I think I can generate a single ```libbfd.a``` supporting both ARM and RISCV. That solution does not specifically fits my question though.

Comment: Those functions are just ones with external linkage. They are directly called in my program like ```printf```. Making the ones having the same name ```static``` will work but it’s not that **elegant**. Many modifications to automatically generated code is required.

Answer (score 0):

> is there an elegant and simple solution to this scenario?

Solutions:

1. Write 2 programs working in a client-server architecture. Two servers are run each one linked with different static library flavor and listening on different sockets.  The client does the work and when he wants to do the work on a specific flavor of `bds`, he calls one of the servers to do the work.

You might roll your own protocol or research some existing [RPC](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rpc.3.html) and use [protobuffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) or similar.

2. Compile `libbfd.a` into a shared library and use `dlopen` to separately reference each shared library flavor.
3. Use `objcopy` to rename all symbols in one static library and provide your own headers with the renamed symbols and link with it normally.

> I cannot break the static libraries into object files.

A static library is an archive of object files. You can always unpack it to object files.

Comment: Can you elaborate on ```2```? Zilog80 mentioned that in comments too. My understanding about the differences between static and dynamic libraries is primitive.

Comment: What's there to elaborate? I think point `2` is long enough to give you enough information to know what to google for. `My understanding about the differences between static and dynamic libraries is primitive.` Then research them?

Comment: Research what is a static library and shared library, see `man ld` and `man ld.so` and `man ar`, research the internet on how to build a shared library, but to be honest `binutils` should already be building a `libbfd.so`, at least it's on my system it's already installed. Then research `dlopen`, see `man dlopen` how to open a shared library _even with an example_ on how to call a function from shared library.